# Number of vector and affine subspaces of dimension $ k$ of $E$ over $\mathbb{F_q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Problem (comments after):

Let $\mathbb{F_q}$ be a finite field of cardinal $q$ and $\mathcal{E}$ an affine espace of dimension $n$ directed by the vector space $E$.

Show that:

1. $\#\left\{\text{vector subspaces of dimension } k \text{ of } E\right\} = \#\{\text{vector subspaces of dimension }k \text{ of }(\mathbb{F_q})^n\}$
2. $\#\{\text{affine subspaces of dimension }k \text{ of }\mathcal{E}\} = \#\{\text{affine subspaces of dimension }k \text{ of }(\mathbb{F_q})^n\}$

It is not the point to calculate those cardinals.
I tried to create a bijection between the sets but nothing.
I know, this must be really easy but I do not see how to solve it.
Can someone help me here, please?

Comment: Vectorial subspaces? I think the term is just "vector subspace".

Comment: I don't see what you want to prove... is $\mathcal E$ not equal to $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$?